# Should `text-align: center;` be applied to the element or its parent container?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center an element.

Should `text-align: center;` be applied to the element or its parent container?

Given this:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>This is a centered header.</h1>
</div>
```

...should I write this:

```
.container {
    text-align: center;
}
```

...or this:

```
.container h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: The answer depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Arbel I'm trying to center an element.

Comment: If you are trying to center text in `h1`, then `.container h1` will be enough, but if you are trying to center `h1` itself, then it's a completely different scenario, since `h1` is a block level element by default and takes all the width available to a block level element in your document's flow where your `h1` element occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both will work. Try it out - here's a JS Fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/a4jmB/

```
.container {
    text-align: center;
}
```

That sets all the text in the parent div to be centered.

```
.container h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

That sets all the text in the h1 div to be centered. 
Basically the h1 takes up the entire row width regardless of the css setting, so the text will be centered.

The second one is probably preferable, though, since it only applies to the h1 div, and not to any other text that might be in the container.

Answer (score 1):

Either will work, if both of their layouts allow them to span the space you want them to centre in. If your `<h1>` has for instance `float:left;` applied, adding `text-align: center;` onto the container will not centre the element; in this case you'd need to add `width:100%; text-align:center;` to the actual `<h1>` element.

Answer (score 0):

It will work fine for all block elements, which are not changed via `float` or `display`.
In the particular case it is important if there is any other content in the `.container`, which shouldn't be centered. Then you should use the second code. Even if you want to expand your code, it makes sence because it is a more clean code.

Answer (score 0):

> The text-align property in CSS is used for aligning the **inner** contents of a **block element**. [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-align/)

The < h1> element is, by default a [block level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements). 
Therefore, it will fill all available width and normally start on a new line.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<head>
    <style>
      h1 { text-align:center;}
    </style>
<head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>This is a centered header.</h1>
    </div>
</body>
<html>
```

As some of the other answers have already mentioned, please note that when applying the 'text-align:center' property and value to *any* element, all child elements will **inherit** the property ***"text-align"*** with the value ***center***, unless specifically unset.

> [W3C Inherited-property Values](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/#inherited-property)

For example :

```
<style>
.container {text-align:center;}
</style>
<div class="container">
    <h1>This is a centered header.</h1>
    <h4>All of the other content on your site</h4>
    <p>Will be centered, because it falls within the .container </p>
    <ul>
        <li>Including:</li> 
        <li>nested elements</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```